# Is CouchRest 1.0.1 compatible with ruby 1.9.2 version

Tags: ruby-1.9.2, couchrest

I am facing issues when making a call to Db using the CouchRest Db when on ruby 1.9.2. the same calls work with ruby version 1.8.7.

Is anyone using COuchrest 1.0.1 with ruby version 1.9.2 or similar.

The error I am getting is -

```
RestClient::BadRequest: 400 Bad Request
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rest-client-1.6.1/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:48:in `return!'
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rest-client-1.6.1/lib/restclient/request.rb:220:in `process_result'
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rest-client-1.6.1/lib/restclient/request.rb:169:in `block in transmit'
    from ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:627:in `start'
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rest-client-1.6.1/lib/restclient/request.rb:166:in `transmit'
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rest-client-1.6.1/lib/restclient/request.rb:60:in `execute'
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rest-client-1.6.1/lib/restclient/request.rb:31:in `execute'
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rest-client-1.6.1/lib/restclient.rb:76:in `put'
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/couchrest-1.0.1/lib/couchrest/rest_api.rb:13:in `put'
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/couchrest-1.0.1/lib/couchrest/database.rb:176:in `save_doc'
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/couchrest-1.0.1/lib/couchrest/document.rb:42:in `save'
    from ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/couchrest-1.0.1/lib/couchrest/design.rb:61:in `save'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this working. There is no compatibility issue, the issue was related to not being able to send database name in query.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. Can you be more specific?  https://gist.github.com/2862111